# how to do i want to put 2-3 recycleview in single activity using volly library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

please help to rectify this problem....i want to put 2-3 recycleview in single activity using volly library i implement but second recycleview is not showing

these class containe 2-3 recycleview with gridviewlayout...in which i want to show  galleries with particular text 
    1st gallery show 5-10 images with header text,2nd gallery will also show images with gallery header text,same with 3rd one....but after doing this 
    1rd recylceview is showing and second one/3rd one is not showing

Gallery_byVolly.java

```
package com.example.gallery;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.admin.app_shewale.R;
import com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Gallery_byVolly extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView gallerygridview1;
    TextView gallerytext;
    List<VikasGallery> gallerylist1;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue,requestQueue2,requestQueue3;
    CardAdapter adapter,adapter2,adapter3;
    private int requestCount = 1;
    public static final String DATA_URL="http://1biz.in/shevale_app/android/shevale_gallery.php?page=";
    public static final String DATA_UR1= "http://1biz.in/shevale_app/android/shevale_gallery.php?page=";
    public static final String DATA_URL2= "http://1biz.in/shevale_app/android/shevale_gallery3.php?page=";
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager,layoutManager2,layoutManager3;
    Context context;


    RecyclerView vollygallerygridview2;
    List<VikasGallery> vollygallerylist2;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_by_volly);

       requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    gallerylist1 = new ArrayList<>();
    gallerygridview1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.vollygallerygridview);
    gallerygridview1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    gallerygridview1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    getData();
    adapter = new CardAdapter(gallerylist1, this);
    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    gallerygridview1.setAdapter(adapter);
    gallerygridview1.addOnItemTouchListener(

            new Recylceviewitelclick(context, new Recylceviewitelclick.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    System.out.println("value of this is:" + position);
                    Toast.makeText(Gallery_byVolly.this, "value of this is" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_Full_Gallery.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("vollygalleryposition", position);
                    bundle.putSerializable("listimages", (Serializable) gallerylist1);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    System.out.println("value oofd getpostion" + position);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            })
    );
    gallerygridview1.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(gallerygridview1)) {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData();
            }
        }
    });
    vollygallerygridview2=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.vollygallerygridview2);
    vollygallerygridview2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    vollygallerylist2=new ArrayList<>();
    layoutManager2 = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    vollygallerygridview2.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
    getData2();
    adapter2 = new CardAdapter(vollygallerylist2, this);
    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    vollygallerygridview2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    vollygallerygridview2.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
        {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (isLastItemDisplaying(vollygallerygridview2))
            {
                //Calling the method getdata again
                getData2();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void getData2()
{
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer2(requestCount));
    requestCount++;
}

private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer2(int requestCount)
{


    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL2 + String.valueOf(requestCount),new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
        {
            //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
            System.out.println("value of response2 is"+response);
            parseData2(response);
            //Hiding the progressbar
          //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                  //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(Gallery_byVolly.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount)
{
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
        {
            //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
            System.out.println("value of response is"+response);
            parseData(response);
            //Hiding the progressbar
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(Gallery_byVolly.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

private void parseData2(JSONArray response)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
    {
        //Creating the superhero object
        VikasGallery superHero = new VikasGallery();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = response.getJSONObject(i);
            //Adding data to the superhero object
            superHero.setImagesurl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the superhero object to the list
        vollygallerylist2.add(superHero);
        System.out.println("value of list2" + vollygallerylist2);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData()
{
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        //Creating the superhero object
        VikasGallery superHero = new VikasGallery();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            //Adding data to the superhero object
            superHero.setImagesurl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the superhero object to the list
        gallerylist1.add(superHero);
        System.out.println("value of list inside  parse m" + gallerylist1);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0)
    {

        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
    //Overriden method to detect scrolling
//    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
//    {
//        //Ifscrolled at last then
//        if (isLastItemDisplaying(gallerygridview1))
//        {
//
//            getData();
//        }
//    }
}
```

adapter class

this is the adapter class of gallery class its basically show images in recycleview ( in listitems) after click on images call next activity that show full images.

```
package com.example.gallery;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.example.admin.app_shewale.R;
import com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery;

import java.util.List;

public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    //List to store all superheroes
    List<VikasGallery> superHeroes;
    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<VikasGallery> superHeroes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
        System.out.println("value of list adapetr" + superHeroes);

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.vollyitemlist, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        VikasGallery superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);
        System.out.println("value of lis is sumit kumawat"+superHeroes);
        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImagesurl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.vikas1, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImagesurl(), imageLoader);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vollyimage);

        }
    }

}
```

Logcat
this is the logatcat that is show the error

```
07-27 07:20:47.113 760-3040/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.admin.app_shewale/com.example.gallery.Gallery_byVolly} from uid 10167 on display 0
07-27 07:20:47.116 760-820/? W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
07-27 07:20:47.129 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of list adapetr[]
07-27 07:20:47.204 12543-12562/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-27 07:20:47.204 12543-12562/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeb8c8c80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-27 07:20:47.219 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.219 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.589 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.589 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.621 760-786/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.admin.app_shewale/com.example.gallery.Gallery_byVolly: +503ms
07-27 07:20:47.654 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of response is[{"image":"http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/djsjqj6l6\/image\/upload\/v1468322269\/gallery\/ashtvinayakdarshan\/gallery1.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/djsjqj6l6\/image\/upload\/v1468322270\/gallery\/ashtvinayakdarshan\/gallery2.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/djsjqj6l6\/image\/upload\/v1468322271\/gallery\/ashtvinayakdarshan\/gallery3.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/djsjqj6l6\/image\/upload\/v1468322272\/gallery\/ashtvinayakdarshan\/gallery4.jpg"}]
07-27 07:20:47.654 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of list inside  parse m[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90]
07-27 07:20:47.654 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of list inside  parse m[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689]
07-27 07:20:47.654 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of list inside  parse m[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@305c668e]
07-27 07:20:47.654 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of list inside  parse m[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@305c668e, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e6b1eaf]
07-27 07:20:47.655 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of lis is sumit kumawat[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@305c668e, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e6b1eaf]
07-27 07:20:47.656 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of lis is sumit kumawat[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@305c668e, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e6b1eaf]
07-27 07:20:47.656 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of lis is sumit kumawat[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@305c668e, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e6b1eaf]
07-27 07:20:47.657 12543-12543/? I/System.out: value of lis is sumit kumawat[com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e1d2d90, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@3ae7689, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@305c668e, com.example.vikaskame.VikasGallery@1e6b1eaf]
07-27 07:20:47.658 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.658 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.995 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:47.995 12543-12543/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
07-27 07:20:48.108 12543-12562/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-27 07:20:48.109 12543-12562/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe245b560, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Explain, why you want to do that?

Comment: means 1 activity contain 3 recycleview each reclyeview with gridlayoutmanager that show imaages from server using volly..but problem is that 1 recycleview show perfect but second one is not showing

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: executing properly but in logcat shwoing that statement...why its happen pls sir help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you use awful variable naming style. Never use digits (1..2...3..) with your repeating variables.

Your logcat show you, that one of the recycler view have not an adapter. I found only one adapter, but I didn't see another. You call `adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();` but did not initialize it.

Edit.

```
 //initializing our adapter
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        gallerygridview1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        getData();
        adapter = new CardAdapter(gallerylist1, this);
```

Where is a second?

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout - told you that there was not any adapter for some of RecyclerViews.

Comment: when i changed vollygallerygridview2.setAdapter(adapter2); inplace of vollygallerygridview2.setAdapter(adapter); show 1st recycleview images.mean arralist can not fetch record from server

Answer (score 0):

The answer is telling you exactly what the problem is. vollygallerygridview2 never has an adapter set on it. Each RecyclerView must have an adapter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to check from the code you've posted your never calling setAdapter on volleygallerygridview2, that's your error.

Comment: mr ben i done everything but 1st recycleview adapter images show in second recycleview but 2nd recycleview is not showing particular images..